# Popup with tabs | jQuery

Tags: jquery-ui, jsp, jquery

I want a popup window to enable when we click a link, where the popup should contain tabs. Is any UI or plugin available ready-made in jQuery? As for jQuery, I want to know if anything suits my requirement. Please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Use [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/). It has everything you need.

As the website says:

> jQuery UI is a curated set of user interface interactions, effects,
>   widgets, and themes built on top of the jQuery JavaScript Library.
>   Whether you're building highly interactive web applications or you
>   just need to add a date picker to a form control, jQuery UI is the
>   perfect choice.

- It has [Popups](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#default)
- It has [Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/)

---

EXAMPLE
An example of tabs within a popup

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-eGE6blurk5sHj+rmkfsGYeKyZx3M4bG+ZlFyA7Kns7E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

    <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
      <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
        
        <div id="tabs">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ulla interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>Mauris eleifend est et tur potenti. Aliquam vulputbitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
      </div>
   </div>
      
   <script>
      $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog({ width: 600 });
      });
   </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery modal](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#default) can be a good choice. You can put any HTML inside modal.